# Date Disappearing from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

So I have this problem right now. I'm writing a mobile app through react native.
The problem is I'm trying to manipulate an array and it seems that a date drops from it for no reason a some point. here is the code and the output that it produces:

```
const res = labelDates.map((val) => {
  const date = new Date();
    date.setTime(0);
    date.setFullYear(val.date.getFullYear());
    date.setMonth(val.date.getMonth());
    date.setDate(val.date.getDate());
    console.log('mapping ' + val.date + ' to ' + date);
    return date;
});
console.log(res);
```

And here is the output

```
mapping Thu Sep 03 2020 16:25:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Thu Sep 03 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Fri Sep 04 2020 16:28:40 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Fri Sep 04 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Sat Sep 05 2020 12:48:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Sat Sep 05 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Sun Sep 06 2020 14:28:56 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Sun Sep 06 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Mon Sep 07 2020 11:28:16 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Mon Sep 07 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Tue Sep 08 2020 18:22:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Tue Sep 08 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Thu Sep 10 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Thu Sep 10 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Fri Sep 11 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Fri Sep 11 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Sat Sep 12 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Sat Sep 12 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Sun Sep 13 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Sun Sep 13 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Mon Sep 14 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Mon Sep 14 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Tue Sep 15 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Tue Sep 15 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Wed Sep 16 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Wed Sep 16 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Thu Sep 17 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Thu Sep 17 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Fri Sep 18 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Fri Sep 18 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Sat Sep 19 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Sat Sep 19 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Sun Sep 20 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Sun Sep 20 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
mapping Mon Sep 21 2020 00:18:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) to Mon Sep 21 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Array [
  2020-09-02T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-03T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-04T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-05T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-06T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-07T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-09T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-10T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-11T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-12T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-13T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-14T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-15T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-16T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-17T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-18T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-19T23:00:00.000Z,
  2020-09-20T23:00:00.000Z,
]
```

As you see during the map call the array is containing the date 2020-09-08, but right after it terminates, my res array has dropped it for no reason!

I am sure data doesn't change since it's hardcoded and there is no other thread handling it.

Comment: Your output after the mapping loop is all in UTC. The new dates in the `.map()` callback are explicitly set to midnight. On planet earth, at any given time, the date of the month is different in different parts of the world.

Comment: I know it's all in UTC that's not the point, a date is missing from there.

Comment: It is not missing. Your Sep 8 date is Sep 7 2 hours west of you.

Comment: What date is missing? Compare the length of the original array and the length of the mapped array. I think you'll f ind they are equal.

Comment: Also you probably should notice that *many* of your dates have changed.